# Integral $\int{\tan^{-1}t\over (1+t²)^{2}}dt$

Tags: calculus

How can I integrate the following

$$\int{\dfrac{\tan^{-1}t}{(1+t^2)^2}}dt$$

Thank you.

Comment: http://wolframalpha.com

Comment: i want to learn the steps, not just know the awnser, anyway thank you.

Comment: Then show us what steps you done and where you get stuck. As it stands this looks like you couldn't be bothered to even try your homework. Good answers are attracted to good questions.

Comment: Sorry if seems like it, actually this is a part on a another integral, was trying to integrate xsinx on the variable x, then i tried to do the substituition x= 2tan^(−1)t  after do it i tried to integrate by parts and one of the parts was the aformentioned integral then this integral i tried to solve by partial fractions without sucess, and then by substituition, without sucess, finally by parts again, without sucess, instead of write all this history with my abd english i tought that just ask would be nice.

Comment: Now you may be frustrated by the answer because it just changes the integral you got into the original one, which would have not happened if you explained your question in details.

Comment: you is right, but i was really interested in how integrate this function, nevertheless from where it come from. Come on, it is a very interesting function to integrate, do not is?

Comment: From your comments you know sufficient techniques to do the integration. You need to focus on your choice of methods. Why when looking at the integral of $x\sin x$ did you choose substitution? Don't you see a more straightforward method to use for that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Plug in $t=\tan \theta$ to get:
$$\int\frac{\theta (\sec^2\theta)d\theta}{\sec^4\theta}$$
$$=\int\theta \cos^2 \theta d\theta$$
$$=\int\frac{\theta (1+\cos 2\theta)}{2}d\theta$$